# PC wont boot either Ubuntu or Windows 7

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. After I installed Ubuntu ran the first time. After I restarted I couldn't get it to boot.

I went on Windows and looked for a fix. I tried it in the terminal, not sure what it was, was like `sudo (something something)`. The command that I used I believe moved something (can't remember).

I then restarted and it took me to the GNU GRUB. I can't reinstall Ubuntu because it won't find a device for boot-loader 
installation.

i think that i had ubuntu working fine when i did the sudo command and that i should have just waited longer for it to start up (could be wrong)
if i can just boot windows i will be happy so if there is a way from the grub menu i will take that
found the command i used not sure if it could have done much harm ---- sudo e2fsck -n -v /dev/sdXY

Comment: Instead of adding comments, please edit your question to keep everything in one place and as clear as possible. This will increase the chance of your question being answered.

Comment: I didn't mean it to sound like a warning, just a friendly suggestion! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get into Windows with the Windows bootmgr, do this:

### Way 1

1. Put the *installation* disc in the CD drive and boot from it.
2. When it shows `Install` dialog, go to the lower left corner and click `Computer repair options`.
3. Then select `Command Prompt` and **type `bootsect /nt60 ALL /force`, `bootrec /fixboot` and then `bootrec /fixmbr`**.
4. Reboot.

### Way 2

1. Put the *installation* disc in the CD drive and boot from it.
2. After it has loaded and you see the first dialog, press [Shift]+[F12].
3. **Type `bootsect /nt60 ALL /force`, `bootrec /fixboot` and then `bootrec /fixmbr`**.
4. Reboot.

### If nothing works

1. Put the *Ubuntu Live CD* or a similar Linux disc in the CD drive and boot from it.
2. Use a partitioning program like GParted to format (*delete*) your Ubuntu partition. You can also format your entire drive to start it all over with a fresh system.

Comment: i will see if this works

Comment: i think that i tried this and it didnt work but i am about to test it

Comment: If this won't work, I'll have to research for more information.

Comment: both commands returned with " the system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Did you use the _installation_ disc?

Comment: i used a recovery disc

Comment: but i was stupid and didnt use the disc before all of this

Comment: Try the new commands (forgot the `bootsect`)

Comment: i will try the edit you made

Comment: when i entered the bootsect command it returned   "Target volumes will be updated with BOOTMGR compatible bootcode. the system partiton was not found: the requested system device cannot be found" and the other commands remainded the same

Comment: i did reboot after and it was of no help

Comment: going to be for now but i will try anything that you can find in the morning also if there is a way to get both i will be happy with that if it works

Comment: how will i know where i put ubuntu

Comment: Download [GParted Live](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.14.1-6/gparted-live-0.14.1-6-i486.iso) and boot from it. The partitions with `ext4` format are Linux, those with `ntfs` are Windows.

Comment: fat16, ntfs, a flagged ntfs, and a unallocated file system are showing  no ext4

Comment: At least you know on which partition your Windows system is. So you can delete the others and execute the commands above.

Comment: the fat16 is from dell they other 2 as you said are microsoft and the unallocated cant be changed

Comment: Did you try `bootrec /nt60 ALL /force`?

Answer (score 0):

e2fsck command is for checking an ext2, 3 or 4 filesystem. It shouldn't do any harm.

Once I wanted to restore Windows XP bootloader, but had trouble doing that with Windows installation CD. I've found something called Rescatux. It's a small Linux liveCD for repairing GRUB, MBR and similar things. It has a beta option to restore Windows bootloader. It worked for me, but may not work for you.

Alternatively you can try to install Ubuntu again (create ext4 partition on unallocated part of hard disk and install it there). If during Ubuntu's installation you are using the advanced partitioning method (not the one with one big slider) then make sure to set your main disk as device for bootloader installation. (Probably it's /dev/sda . Don't choose /dev/sda4 or something else ending with number, because it means "partition with this number". And it won't work.)

Also it would help, if you could run `sudo fdisk -l` and paste output here. It shows info about all disks and partitions.

Comment: i will see if this helps anything